# Spring WS Version 2 to 3

Tags: spring-ws

Recently I have upgraded the Spring WS from 2.x to 3.x, as part of the upgrade, I only modify the interceptor to use org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.

However, now I'm getting following error when using web service. org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: no SOAPAction header!

Is there any implementation change that I need to do for from 2.x to 3.x which I missed?